# index.html page not Loading after json-server --watch pokedb.json --port 5500

Tags: html, json, api, npm-live-server

After installing and running  (`json-server --watch pokedb.json --port 5500`)

Content in my index.html page is not loading. When I open index.html page I get

```
Congrats!
You're successfully running JSON Server
✧*｡٩(ˊᗜˋ*)و✧*｡

Resources
/pokemon 1x
To access and modify resources, you can use any HTTP method:

GET POST PUT PATCH DELETE OPTIONS

undefined
Documentation
README

To replace this page, create a ./public/index.html file.
```

Does anyone know how I can get this to run properly?